# Size of Quotient Group

Tags: group-theory, quotient-group

For a quotient group G/H (where H is a normal subgroup), is |G/H|=|G|/|H|?

i.e. is the size of the quotient group = (size of G)/(size of H)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Let $p:G\rightarrow G/H$, the size of $p^{-1}(y)$ is the size of $H$. To see this, remark that  $p^{-1}(1_{G/H})=H$ and if $p(x)=y$, the map $p^{-1}(y)\rightarrow H$ defined by $z\rightarrow x^{-1}z$ is a bijection whose inverse is $z\rightarrow xz$. $G$ is the disjoint union of $\{p^{-1}(y), y\in G/H\}$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and this follows immediately from [Lagrange's theorem](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem).